# Как прописать текст внутри input type="checkbox" в html

Tags: html

Как вместо галочки вставить внутри input произвольный текст в html-код, не используя css и javascript

```html
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" checked />
</label>
```

Comment: `не используя css и javascript` Прям в `input[type=checkbox]` - никак.

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: с `css`-ом можно через `before` вывести текст непосредственно в `input[type=checkbox]`. Правда нужно ещё задать `appearance: none; -webkit-appearance: none`